# submodules of $\mathbb{Q}$ over a p-adic fraction ring

Tags: ring-theory

how to see that there are only two Z$_($$_2$$_)$-submodules of $\mathbb{Q}$, namely, Z$_($$_2$$_)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ (up to isomorphism)?

This is from Page 188 of Introduction to Homological Algebra by Rotman. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't even true, there are other submodules, namely $2^n\mathbb Z_{(2)}$ for any $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: what if I added "up to isomorphism"? thx